# How redirect respective controller into "$routeProvider"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I would like to know if is possible change the next normal code into an Angular app:

This is how the **index.html** file has:

```
<!-- Load Controllers. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/controller_1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/controller_2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/controller_3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/controller_4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/controller_5.js"></script>
```

And the **app.js** file has the next part:

```
$routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    controller: 'controller_1',
    templateUrl: 'views/views-1.html'
  }).
  when('/menu/:restaurantId', {
    controller: 'controller_2',
    templateUrl: 'views/views-2.html'
  }).
  when('/checkout', {
    controller: 'controller_3',
    templateUrl: 'views/views-3.html'
  }).
  when('/thank-you', {
    controller: 'controller_4',
    templateUrl: 'views/views-4.html'
  }).
  when('/customer', {
    controller: 'controller_5',
    templateUrl: 'views/views-5.html'
  });
```

});

**_______________________________________________________________**

My problem is: I don't wanna make all that includes into the ***index.html***

**¿how can i tell you to my *app.js*, where is the controller for the respective view?**

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs

Comment: If you're using grunt with your app grunt-include-replace could be nice here. This way you can have your includes specified in a seperate file and add them to your index with one line. Much cleaner
https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-include-replace

Comment: Can you give a small example how to do it? because is a little difficult for me understand this. it means, using "resolveController" and "grunt-include-replace"
Thanks